# InputType textpassword in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml, android-textinputlayout

I have created a form in the android app. It looks something like this.
[image: Screenshot]
What I want is the text appearance in all the hints to be cosistent. If I use inputType = "textpassword" it gives the effect of confirm password which is different(bold) from other view. The field password has also same input type but the editext is not inside textInputlayout. The code for fields are as follows

### 1>password field

```
 <EditText
       android:id="@+id/registerPasswordEt"
       fontPath="fonts/Proxima_Nova_Light.ttf"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="Password *"
       android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
       android:textStyle="normal"
       android:inputType="textPassword"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:nextFocusDown="@+id/registerConfirmPasswordEt" />
```

2> Confirm password

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_confirm_password" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/input_layout_password">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/registerConfirmPasswordEt"
                fontPath="fonts/Proxima_Nova_Light.ttf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:hint="Confirm Password ( must match password ) *"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/registerUserNameEt"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

3> Other field

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_last_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/registerLastNameEt"
                        fontPath="fonts/Proxima_Nova_Light.ttf"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Last Name *"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/registerPasswordEt" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

What I want is all texts to look similar and I need TextInputLayout for animation effects. Is there a way to make the text appearance same?

Comment: Try removing font family from confirm password field as you already have applied font to that edittext field and check in UI.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. As you see in the image the field has hint in bold but other(font size etc) seem to be fine. If the texinputlayout bracketing the editext is removed the view behaves as expected but I need it to be bracketed by the textinputlayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of the library calligraphy. Above issue occurs when you have calligraphy library and edittext with inputtype textpassword inside TextInputLayout. The solution I found are as follows.

```
Typeface confirmPasswordFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), CalligraphyConfig.get().getFontPath());
        inputLayoutConfirmPassword.setTypeface(confirmPasswordFace);  // or Typeface.NORMAL or any other

        CalligraphyTypefaceSpan confrmPasswordTypefaceSpan = TypefaceUtils.getSpan(confirmPasswordFace);
        SpannableString spannableConfirmPasswordHint = new SpannableString("Confirm Password ( must match password ) *");
        spannableConfirmPasswordHint.setSpan(confrmPasswordTypefaceSpan, 0, spannableConfirmPasswordHint.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        inputLayoutConfirmPassword.setHint(spannableConfirmPasswordHint);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove inputType from editText from xml file and add following line in your java code :

```
EditText registerConfirmPasswordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerConfirmPasswordEt_text);
registerConfirmPasswordEt.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Comment: It works only if you don't have textinputlayout bracketing the edittext.

Comment: No. I have used it in my many codes having textinputlayout. It works fine.

Comment: Not worked for me. I have `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I put your code and it shows confirm password field same as other fields... I am posting code below, correct me If I am wrong (fontPath lib is not used in this code)...

[Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/f5pyk6)

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_confirm_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/inputLayout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/registerConfirmPasswordEt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:hint="Confirm Password ( must match password ) *"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/registerUserNameEt"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_last_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/inputLayout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/registerLastNameEt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Last Name *"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/registerPasswordEt" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I found the issue was little different. I have mentioned them in my answer below

Comment: I just posted the answer please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not in the library calligraphy. I have try to remove it and use a native Font xml*,  but have the same issue.

In my case inspired by SarojMjn  hi fix the view using this method

```
public static  void fixHintTextInputLayoutForPassword(Context context, TextInputLayout password,CharSequence text){
    SpannableString spannableConfirmPasswordHint = new SpannableString(text);
    spannableConfirmPasswordHint.setSpan(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.lato_light), 0, spannableConfirmPasswordHint.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    password.setHint(spannableConfirmPasswordHint);
    password.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.lato_light));
}
```

migration to the native xml font was simple but the final result is not really good in my case, see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683352/how-to-enable-antialiasing-using-font-in-xml-android)