# How to enable antialiasing when using Android Custom fonts on my App?

Tags: android, fonts, calligraphy

I removed chrisjenx/Calligraphy library to use a native Font XML on Android app [android official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html).

The replace activity was simple but now te font is rendered without antialiasing, in the  light fonts the difference is evident.
I have used the same ttf font (lato-light.ttf).

Any help or ideas?  [image]

the top is rendered natively,
the bottom is rendered with calligraphy.

the font is  [Lato - Light](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato?selection.family=Lato)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found is return back on chrisjenx/Calligraphy library.